# How to search inside PDF files

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I have to search inside PDF files for an upcoming (ASP.NET MVC) project in shared hosting environment. What is the best solution? Any third part product?

Answer (score 1):

[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) is a popular choice.   See [Lucene FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#head-c45f8b25d786f4e384936fa93ce1137a23b7e422) on searching pdfs.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene is a good choice - for ASP.NET, using [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) is the best bet. Lucene is an indexing engine only, meaning you'll have to provide it with the text from the PDF. If you have access to the web server, you can install an [IFilter](http://www.ifilter.org/) for this (I recommend [Foxit's](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/ifilter/) PDF filter). Otherwise you'll have to get hold of some code to use on your website to parse and filter the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) can help with such task.

The library could be used to [extract text](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/pdf-text/extract) (with or without formatting). The extracted text can be used to create an index. You can even use `String.IndexOf` method if you just want to know if a PDF file contains a given text.

The library can also [retrieve a collection of words](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Text/ExtractTextByWords) with their bounding rectangles from PDFs. This might be useful if you need to know exact position of a text in a file.

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.